# Convert INT_MAX to float and then back to integer.

Tags: c, type-conversion, integer-overflow

In C programming, I find a weird problem, which counters my intuition. When I declare a `integer` as the `INT_MAX` (`2147483647`, defined in the limits.h) and implicitly convert it to a `float` value, it works fine, i.e., the float value is same with the maximum integer. And then, I convert the float back to an integer, something interesting happens. The new `integer` becomes the minimum integer (`-2147483648`).
The source codes look as below:

```
int a = INT_MAX;
float b = a; // b is correct
int a_new = b; // a_new becomes INT_MIN
```

I am not sure what happens when the float number `b` is converted to the integer `a_new`. So, is there any reasonable solution to find the maximum value which can be switched forth and back between `integer` and `float` type?

PS: The value of `INT_MAX` - 100 works fine, but this is just an arbitrary workaround.

Comment: floating point has only limited precision so I don't think this conversion is weird.

Comment: Contrary to your comment, `b` is *not* correct. If you look at it closely I think you'll find it is actually `INT_MAX+1` after the first conversion. `INT_MAX` on your platform is 2147483647, *not* 2147483648. I.e., the *first* conversion is where the resulting delta is first introduced. [**See it live**](http://ideone.com/A9duGf)

Comment: A 4-byte float uses 23 bits to store the mantissa and 9 to store the sign and exponent.  This means that storing the largest 32-bit integers cannot be done completely accurately.

Comment: It looks like the problem doesn't happen on all platforms: see [example here](http://ideone.com/cNP5te)

Comment: @AurélienGasser It's a fallacy.  I'm sure that the compiler optimizes by default.  Disable the optimizations and then see the results.  The number in question cannot be represented exactly as a floating point, so there is no way to get it back.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This answer assumes that `float` is an IEEE-754 single precision float encoded as 32-bits, and that an `int` is 32-bits.  See [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Internal_representation) for more information about IEEE-754.

---

Floating point numbers only have 24-bits of precision, compared with 32-bits for an int.  Therefore int values from 0 to 16777215 have an exact representation as floating point numbers, but numbers greater than 16777215 do not necessarily have exact representations as floats.  The following code demonstrates this fact (on systems that use IEEE-754).

```
for ( int a = 16777210; a < 16777224; a++ )
{
    float b = a;
    int c = b;
    printf( "a=%d c=%d b=0x%08x\n", a, c, *((int*)&b) );
}
```

The expected output is

```
a=16777210 c=16777210 b=0x4b7ffffa
a=16777211 c=16777211 b=0x4b7ffffb
a=16777212 c=16777212 b=0x4b7ffffc
a=16777213 c=16777213 b=0x4b7ffffd
a=16777214 c=16777214 b=0x4b7ffffe
a=16777215 c=16777215 b=0x4b7fffff
a=16777216 c=16777216 b=0x4b800000
a=16777217 c=16777216 b=0x4b800000
a=16777218 c=16777218 b=0x4b800001
a=16777219 c=16777220 b=0x4b800002
a=16777220 c=16777220 b=0x4b800002
a=16777221 c=16777220 b=0x4b800002
a=16777222 c=16777222 b=0x4b800003
a=16777223 c=16777224 b=0x4b800004
```

Of interest here is that the `float` value 0x4b800002 is used to represent the three `int` values 16777219, 16777220, and 16777221, and thus converting 16777219 to a `float` and back to an `int` does not preserve the exact value of the `int`.

---

The two floating point values that are closest to `INT_MAX` are 2147483520 and 2147483648, which can be demonstrated with this code

```
for ( int a = 2147483520; a < 2147483647; a++ )
{
    float b = a;
    int c = b;
    printf( "a=%d c=%d b=0x%08x\n", a, c, *((int*)&b) );
}
```

The interesting parts of the output are

```
a=2147483520 c=2147483520 b=0x4effffff
a=2147483521 c=2147483520 b=0x4effffff
...
a=2147483582 c=2147483520 b=0x4effffff
a=2147483583 c=2147483520 b=0x4effffff
a=2147483584 c=-2147483648 b=0x4f000000
a=2147483585 c=-2147483648 b=0x4f000000
...
a=2147483645 c=-2147483648 b=0x4f000000
a=2147483646 c=-2147483648 b=0x4f000000
```

Note that all 32-bit `int` values from 2147483584 to 2147483647 will be rounded up to a `float` value of 2147483648. The largest `int` value that will round down is 2147483583, which the same as `(INT_MAX - 64)` on a 32-bit system.

One might conclude therefore that numbers below `(INT_MAX - 64)` will safely convert from `int` to `float` and back to `int`. But that is only true on systems where the size of an `int` is 32-bits, and a `float` is encoded per IEEE-754.