# Why does converting int to float lose precision in C programming language

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I run this code

```
int a, b;
float t;
a = 18642731;  //16777217:16777217 16777216.000000 16777216
t = (float)a;
b = (int)t;
if (a != b)printf("%d %f %d\n", a, t, b);
```

The output is

```
18642731 18642732.000000 18642732
```

The compiler is gcc 9.3.0.
Why is `t` not the value of `18642731.000000`

Comment: It's because the IEEE standard see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

Comment: `18642731` in binary is `1000111000111011100101011` which needs 26 bits. The IEEE `float` (single-precision) type has `24 + 1` bits of precision.

Comment: int and float have the same size in most implementations, so obviously for float to have larger range then it'll lose some precision. Duplicates: [Strange behavior when casting an int to float in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27113114/995714), [Understanding casts from integer to float](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50319530/995714), [Casting int to float changes value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54812314/995714)

Comment: Oops ... single precision IEEE floating point has `23 + 1` bits of precision. My previous comment is wrong in this regard.

Comment: An easy way to see the problem is this: in that platform both `int`s and `float` use 4 bytes and there are 4294967296 possible distinct quadruplets of bytes. There are indeed 4294967296 distinct values for signed integers (from -2147483648 to 2147483647)... If floats were able to represent any integer what combination of 4 bytes should be used for say `0.5`? All of them are already taken by integers! ... this means that if you can have `0.5` (that is not an integer) then some integer must not be representable in a float.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does converting int to float lose precision in C programming language

Because `float` type is a **finite** precision floating point type. It cannot represent all numbers. If you convert a non-representable number to `float`, then you lose precision.

It just so happens that 18642731 is not representable by `float` on the system where you ran the program.